# What is the correct way to implement heavy-write persistent memory?

Tags: non-volatile-memory

I'm designing a current meter, which should retain the Ampere-hour count during power loss (e.g. power cable is disconnected without regard for first saving the data). The Ampere-hour value could be written every 60 seconds, e.g. +500k writes per year.

I was considering EEPROM, but commonly only support up to 100k writes.
But perhaps by using a 32k memory space, each byte could be cycled 100k times? And using a few seperate bytes for keeping track of the current address, as well as counting every 1k writes or similar, to essentially achieve a small storage with high number of writes?

Another way could be to use volatile memory with a battery, to sustain for at least a few days.

Or, a power-loss detection circuit, and just enough backup power, to allow the MCU to write the current state before shutting down.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Have you looked at alternative NVM technologies such as MRAM or FeRAM?

Comment: The better way is to use ram and detect power loss and then save, no reason to wear out a flash/eeprom or other media.  It doesnt take much of a cap to keep the mcu alive for an order of magnitude longer than you need to save data to the flash/eeprom in the mcu.